# Slider error always Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Use of everything done. No output only shows an error.   Have tried all these ways but it only shows an error. Totally lost it. Nothing is moving forward from yesterday. Kindly look into it and please let me know.

```
public class task {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "g://geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.cheapoair.com/");
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember746']")).sendKeys("DFW");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember751']")).sendKeys("JFK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='owFlight']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='departCalendar_0']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
    [@id='calendarCompId']/section/div/div[1]/ol/div[26]/li")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember751']")).sendKeys("JFK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='owFlight']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
    [@id='ember730']/section/form/input")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



    //WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
     [@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
    //WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
    [@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]"));
    //a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();

      WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
      [@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
       //WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.id("DivDepart"));
     Actions a = new Actions(driver);


      //a.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build().perform();


      //a.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(30, 
       0).release(slider).build().perform();
            //System.out.println("moved");
                   //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action dragAndDrop =

           a.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(40,0).release().build();

          dragAndDrop.perform();


           //js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(200,0)");

             }

             }
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? What error have you encountered? Dumping the code in StackOverflow does not help generally..

Comment: Am trying to move the slider, after I enter cheapOair.com, after entering the details using xpath and clicking on the search button, new page apperas. Now here I need to move the slider. When am trying to move it, it doesn't work.

Comment: What error does it put?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (72.83332824707031, 791.0833129882812) is out of bounds of viewport width (1269) and height (686)

Comment: JavaScript warning: https://www.cheapoair.com/fpnext/js/jquery?version=5.0.506, line 1683: Using //@ to indicate sourceURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript warning: https://www.cheapoair.com/fpnext/js/jquery?version=5.0.506 line 1 > eval, line 1683: Using //@ to indicate sourceURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead

Answer (score 1):

**Note :-**

In your code I can see clearly that, you have not selected depart date and arrival date and you are directly clicking on "Search Now" button. Validation messages are appearing if you directly click on search button without selecting depart and arrival date. So webdriver is not able to find the slider that your are interested in. **Code you have written for slider is working fine. Do not change it.**

```
public class task {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.cheapoair.com/");
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember746']")).sendKeys("DFW");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember751']")).sendKeys("JFK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='owFlight']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='departCalendar_0']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calendarCompId']/section/div/div[1]/ol/div[26]/li")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember751']")).sendKeys("JFK");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='owFlight']")).click();

    //------- Corrections
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='departCalendar_0']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='calendarCompId']/section/div/div[1]/ol/div[27]/li")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='calendarCompId']/section/div/div[1]/ol/div[31]/li")).click();

     // Corrections--------

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ember730']/section/form/input")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]"));

      WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));

     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("scrollBy(0,500);");

     Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action dragAndDrop =

           a.clickAndHold(slider).moveByOffset(40,0).release().build();
           dragAndDrop.perform();
} }
```

**Just Execute this code, I have executed this and working fine and as expected.**

**I just picked your code and executed once, After correction now it is working very fine. Your Slider code is perfect no need of change in it.**

**Issue was you had not written script for selecting dates[departure and arrival]**

You can also try this code to move Slider :

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
    Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement zero = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='DivDepart']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]"));
    builder1.dragAndDropBy(zero, 1000, 0).perform();

 xpath of slider square :- //*[@id='slider-range']/span[1]
```

Please let me know if it is working at your end.

Comment: Thank you so much, and as you mentioned I haven't written script for selecting dates and there was my error. Now I have tried your code and it perfectly works.

Comment: For example if the flight timing slider is between 10:00 am and 10:20pm, some results display. The results displayed are the timings between 10:01 am and 10:20pm only. Now can I compare and prove the timing 10:01am displayed in result is greater than 10:00am on the slider bar. Am unable to find the logic here. Used list<webelement> and for loop but by that I can only get the texts (using gettext())

Comment: Sry I didn't get your question that you mentioned in comment, pls be more elaborative.. so that i will able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

After entering From/To & date details when user clicks 'Search' button. Then moves to next screen. From there I believe you would like to move the slider. Then try following code and you may have to alter wait based on application need.

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
    rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```